# Facebook: Posting multiple links using graph API (javascript sdk)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My requirement is in such a way that when the user clicks on the button, content similar as below has to be posted on the user's wall from our site.

**Sample Sharing Content**

```
I like the following pages in xyz.com

  1. link 1
  2. link 2
  3. link 3
  4. link 4
```

Is this achievable through facebook graph API[javascript sdk]? If so how can it be done?

**EDIT**

Currently I am able to do the above but I wanna share a link with a clickable text and url. For example instead of displaying `http://www.google.com`, I want to display `Google` as the url text.

Instead of having this http://www.google.com, I wanna do this [Google](http://www.google.com)

Can that be done? Is it possible through API?

Comment: Is this what you want?

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=458358780877780&link=https://www.google.com&picture=https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png&name=Google&redirect_uri=https://mighty-lowlands-6381.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Nope.. That is the link parameter. I am passing all my content via message since it has many links and text content.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You first have to register an app on Facebook. Then you create a login for the user with the right permissions. And finally, you make an Api call to publish your content to their wall.

Registering app & login: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Api call: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Let me know if you have any questions..

Comment: I am doing all those mentioned but now, when I am trying to post I get the following error: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Comment: Did you use the publish_actions permission when logging in the user? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/

Comment: I have added the publish_action permission to the app. But still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like [collections](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/). Take a look at [this example image](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/cfs-ak-prn1/676434/492/442052735871758-/Screen%20Shot%202013-03-11%20at%203.06.59%20PM.png).

This cannot be done in an quick way. You need to fiddle around with the open graph and its actions. This might be a lot to do at first, but the results are very nice (as the different screenshots/app examples demonstrate). The docs are quite good on the basics and there are plenty of ressources on how to archive advaned stuff. But the basics should be enough for a simple link list. Note that this is not just result in "regular" wall post but a collection of links in the users profile, that can also appear on his wall.

You cannot just use "vanilla HTML" to post these collections of link like you want to since it is neither supported, proposes good security not UX compatible.